# Linux Fedora 20:How to use microsoft word, possibly with wine?

Tags: linux, wine

I have searched the Internet for answers to this question, and find a lot of confusing answers.

I have had Linux Fedora 20 installed on my wife's computer, dual boot with Windows, and suggested LibreOffice as an alternative to the Microsoft Word that she has been using. Unfortunately there is no LibreOffice equivalent of the font she likes. She had bought Word on a disk  with the computer, so it seems that the obvious way out is for her to use Word from within Linux, possibly with "wine".

I have not used wine before.

I am reluctant for her to want to go back to Windows, after having Linux installed, with the speed, freedom from attack, and stability she now enjoys.

So, my question is: please, how do we go about this?

Comment: You might want to look at this first: http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=10

Comment: Did you try to install the fonts you want?

Comment: I'm a little pessimistic when it comes to Wine (numerous bad experiences, even with supposedly gold/platinum applications). You are probably much better off installing the font for Linux (fonts can be used by many applications, it does not necessarily have to come with LibreOffice). If you name the font, maybe someone can help.

Comment: What version of Word (2007/2010/2013) is she using?

Answer (score 5):

LibreOffice is a far cry from being compatible with Office. Excel compatibility isn't too bad for calculations, but LibreOffice Writer and Impress can't cope with formatting from Word and Powerpoint. Libreoffice and MS Office are roughly equivalent in functionality, but if you need formatting compatibility, you need to use the same software. (I wish it wasn't the case, but I have to use MS Office for work because I have to work with people who use MS Office.)

You can copy the fonts from Windows to Linux — just drop the files in the directory `~/.fonts`. But fonts aren't the only problem.

Wishing to avoid Windows and run Word directly in Wine looks attractive on paper. But Wine isn't a panacea: it tries to be compatible, but emulating a whole huge, incompletely-documented operating system is an impossible task. There will always be incompatibilities.

Dual boot is very bad user experience: switching between operating systems takes a long time. Dual boot was something we did in the 1990s because individuals or even small institutions couldn't afford virtual machines. It is an obsolete concept.

Run Windows in a virtual machine. I believe that current licenses allow running one instance of Windows, either on the bare metal or inside a virtual machine (but check your license, especially as there are many different editions of Windows). Of the major VM software, VirtualBox is the easiest to get running for this kind of casual use. So install Windows and Office inside a VirtualBox machine. Use Windows just for the software that requires it — do your browsing, file management, etc. in Linux.

Answer (score 2):

I have successfully installed and run Office 2007 (disclaimer: only tested Word and Excel) with Wine in Debian. I don't know if newer versions of Office will work: you might want to give it a try.

But this should not needed if all you want are fonts: try installing the font (drop it in `~/.fonts`) and using them in LibreOffice. You might be able to copy them from a Windows install.

Comment: As an aside, I use Crossover (it is a commercially-supported version of Wine) and Office 2007 (Word, Excel, Powerpoint) work just ok too. (Not related to them --- just a happy client).

Answer (score -3):

Try Installing Word on the windows partition and then copy the installed files into `.wine/drive_c/....` then you could make a shortcut icon using the package `wine-launcher-creator` if you want to. You could also directly launch the application with wine by double clicking.

Comment: -1: it won't work, most Windows software creates registry entries, registers DLLs etc...